# Is CPanel: SSL certificate installed correctly?

Tags: security-certificate, cpanel

My web host said they installed an SSL certificate for me.

On Cpanel, in the SSL tab, is has the following:

```
SSL status   Enabled   
CA certificate   Not installed
```

Is this what it should say if they have done the job properly?

Answer (score 1):

A CSR request, along with a Private Key, is required if you want to use an SSL certificate on your site.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check would be to simply go to `https://yourdomain.com` (replace yourdomain with your domain name) and see what does your browser tell you - is there a green icon in or near your URL bar (usually with a lock)?

**When you click on this icon - does it tell you that the site identity has been verified or there are any warnings?**